# Using lists and Arrays in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, loops, if-statement, for-loop

```
def filter(data : Array[Int]) : Array[Int] = {


    var list: List[Int] = List();
    var index = 0;

    for(index <- data){
        if(index % 2 == 0){
        list.add(index);
        }
    }
    var myArray = new Array[Int](list.length);
    index = 0;
    for(index <- list){
        myArray(index) = index;
    }

    return myArray;


}
```

The array is meant to take data and filter all even numbers and return it, when i return it, it has lots of zeros added into the array. Please help? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure `myArray(index) = index;` is what you want?

Comment: @dimo414 I need to return an array for the test provided by the university, is that wrong code to put the elements from the list into the array or?

Comment: As an aside, that is _not_ the default `List` for Scala.  When using something nonstandard, it helps to say what it is.

Comment: I didnt know it wasnt no standard, I started this language 3 weeks ago?

Comment: The standard `List` is immutable and has no `add` method.  You would write something like `list = index :: list`, but that would add in reverse order, so you'd then need something like `for (index <- list.reverse)`.  If this code actually runs for you, there must be some `import` statement that shadows the normal `scala.collection.immutable.List` with something else.  Maybe, since you're taking a class, it's provided as a standard class import that you don't think about any more?  Anyway, whatever it is, please be aware that this `List` is not part of the standard Scala collections!

Comment: Ive done it now, thank alot @RexKerr for that information! Helped so much! BUT, instead of using 'immutable.list' i had to use 'mutable.list'

Comment: There is no `scala.collection.mutable.List`.  There is a `LinkedList`, which is deprecated as it exposes too many internals to make it safe to use with the full set of collections operations, and a `ListBuffer` which is okay.  Neither provide an `add` method; you would use `+=` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
def filter(data: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    data filter (_ % 2 == 0);
  }
```